# Mysql INSERT syntax error #1064

Tags: mysql, syntax, insert

I keep getting the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

when I try to run this query in phpMyAdmin:

```
INSERT INTO access_log ( 
  idStaff, validSession, attempts, remoteHost, remoteAddress, remoteTime, banned,
  errorNumber,errorMessage,userName ) 
VALUES ( '1','1','1','voidDNS','188.25.3.105','1388877754','','','','pinochio';
```

My table has these columns and their type in this order is (except an auto-increment column 'entry"):

> INT, TINYINT, INT, TEXT, VARCHAR(20), BIGINT( I was afraid of using TIMESTAMP), TINYINT, INT, TEXT, VARCHAR(24).

The query is generated by php automatically, this is why every value has quotes, which I understand shouldn't generate an error.

Can anyone see what's wrong here?

Comment: It's amazing what a little formatting will do. You're lacking a closing parenthesis on your `VALUES` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack simply closing parentheses at the end of query

Comment: I think you mean closing bracket/parentheses

Comment: There are two main problems here:
1. I shouldn't work till 3 o'clock at night.
2. Thanks a lot you didn't get me banned for such a stupid question!

If it wasn't a webpage you could have heard the sound of my hand when I hit my front head!
Thanks again. I lost 3 hours, for this stupid  closing parentheses!

Comment: These things happen. What you can do is shut down or hibernate your pc and then rest your mind a bit and then you're well relaxed try again. Have stayed a whole day behind a semicolon in php. All it takes is learning to stop when saturate and then return. ;)